# In mysql insert data

Tags: mysql, insert-update, alter-table, sql-insert

OK  folks I have to idea on how to start this & need some guidance. I need to insert new customers (designated as individual or business & create an officer for a business. Using different account types assign new accounts to the new customers. Insert a new branch & new employee to i. Then using the new branch, add transactions to the new accounts.

I'm not sure whether to use `INSERT` statements or `ALTER TABLE` or if I should just create an entirely new table. The current tables are: account, branch, business, customer, employee, individual, officer, transaction.

When I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO customer (cust_type_cd) VALUES('I'),('B');
```

I got this message:

> Error Code: 1364 Field 'fed_id' doesn't have a default value

which makes no sense to me. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here's the structure:

**Table account :**

```
`account_id`, `product_cd`, `cust_id`, `open_date`, `close_date`, `last_activity_date`, `status`, `open_branch_id`, `open_emp_id`, `avail_balance`, `pending_balance`
```

**Table branch :**

```
`branch_id`, `name, address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`
```

**Table business :**

```
cust_id, name, state_id, incorp_date
```

**Table customer**

```
`cust_id, fed_id, cust_type_cd, address, city, state, postal_code`
```

**Table employee :**

```
`emp_id, fname, lname, start_date, end_date, superior_emp_id, dept_id, title, assigned_branch_id`
```

**Table individual**

```
cust_id, fname, lname, birth_date
```

**Table officer :**

```
`officer_id, cust_id, fname, lname, title, start_date, end_date`
```

**Table transaction**

```
`txn_id, txn_date, account_id, txn_type_cd, amount, teller_emp_id, execution_branch_id, funds_avail_date`
```

Comment: You have other fields in your customer table that cannot be NULL -- in this case, fed_id.

Comment: can you post your customer table structure?

Comment: This is really too vague of a question to possibly answer here. I am not trying to be rude hear, but the best advice I can give you is to start reading up on basic SQL in general and MySQL in particular as it seems pretty clear you have a lot of learning to do (for example not knowing difference between INSERT queries and ALTER TABLE queries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a default value for the `fed_id` field in your `customer` table.

You could either add a default value to the field:

```
ALTER TABLE customer MODIFY fed_id INT NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

or modify your `INSERT` statement to provide a value:

```
INSERT INTO customer
 (cust_type_cd,fed_id)
VALUES('I',0),('B',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will receive this error if fields in your table are required and cannot be NULL.  You need to insert into all your fields, in this case, at minimum, the fed_id field:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (cust_type_cd, fed_id) 
VALUES ('I', 1);
```

If other fields are required, you may continue to receive a similar error.  Need to see your table structure to understand that.